# Substituting variables into strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Currently I know that we can do something like

```
"This is a string with var %(sub_var)s that will be substituted" % ({'sub_var': 'a1234'})
```

That will sub in the `sub_var` variable into the string. However is there a way to define a string like this:

```
a = "This is a string with var %(sub_var)s that will be substituted"
```

Without defining that `sub_var` until the string `a` is actually used? I have some variables that can change depending on the condition, and I don't want to have to keep retyping `a`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try exactly what you said?

```
   a = "This is a string with var %(sub_var)s that will be substituted"
=> None
   a
=> 'This is a string with var %(sub_var)s that will be substituted'
   a % {'sub_var': 'c'}
=> 'This is a string with var c that will be substituted'
```

Answer (score 0):

Store a function in the variable that can be used to make the strings:

```
>>a='Variable is {}'.format
>>print(a('one'))
Variable is one
>>print(a('two'))
Variable is two
```